# React Nativation in React Native app stopped working

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

My navigation in React Native stopped working. I'm using React Navigation.
I did not change anything in navigation ( at least I don't associate ) and suddenly BottomTab Navigation disappeared and navigation button stopped working. The comment after pushing the button is that payload in not handled by any navigator.
Can You please look at it and advise what is wrong ?
As I wrote, I rather didn't change anything in navigation, I was preparing React Context API once is stopped working .

https://github.com/marcinb1986/database

Comment: Can my answer help you? If no, please provide more details for us.

Comment: Yes, it was great. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the commit, there was a change of your `Stack.Navigator` 7 days ago, the Root was changed from `BottomTabNavigator` to `TabOneScreen`, so the bottom navigation is disppeared.

The changes in commit:
https://github.com/marcinb1986/database/blob/1bf4866f12d7ba97f8f011ee65486923e2a98a3f/navigation/index.tsx

To display the bottom navigator, change the Root back to `BottomTabNavigator`:

**navigation/index.tsx**

```js
...

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} /> <--- BottomTabNavigator
      <Stack.Screen
        name="NotFound"
        component={NotFoundScreen}
        options={{ title: "Oops!" }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```